# Force a 403 response to xml file in Wordpress

Tags: htaccess, xml

I'm looking to force a 403 access denied response for an xml file in a directory outside of the default Wordpress install.

The url I'm trying to force the 403 response on looks like this mydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

I've tried modifying the default Wordpress htaccess file by adding a line to ignore the custom directory but it doesn't seem to work. When visiting the url I get a 404. I did create the directory and xml file and pushed them to our server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(autodiscover)($|/) – [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.(xml)$">
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Wondering if anyone has every run into this before and if they found a solution. My end goal would be to just force the 403 on the one file so my xml sitemaps don't get blocked as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So to restate your question you want `mydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` to produce a 403, and your Wordpress installation is at `mydomain.com/` ?

Then this should do it to match that specific file only:

```
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml - [R=403,NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Would that RewriteRule get added to where I have my current rule: RewriteRule ^(autodiscover)($|/) – [L]

Comment: Yes, it should go there

Comment: Added the line and cleared my sites cache but it's still throwing a 404. Any suggestions for trouble shooting?

Comment: Try a simpler rule until it matches to confirm your .htaccess is working. Try remove that <Files> section

Comment: I removed that but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked was adding an htaccess file to the directory with the line below

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```